# Excel VBA - Extracting data from web page

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to pull seller information from Amazon page with price by automating web browser. I am trying to run the below code, but the error I am getting is:

> Object Variable or With Block variable not set.

Can someone guide me where i am going wrong.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RunNewModule()  
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.Navigate "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00SVA81Z2/ref=dp_olp_new_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=new"
    Dim priceData As Variant
    Dim sellerdata As Variant
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim cntr As Integer
    priceData = html.getElementsByClassName("olpOfferPrice").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    cntr = 1
    For Each item In priceData
        Range("B" & cntr) = item.innerText
        cntr = cntr + 1
    Next item
    sellerdata = html.getElementsByClassName("olpSellerName").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText    
    cntr = 1
    For Each item In sellerdata
        Range("A" & cntr) = item.innerText
        cntr = cntr + 1
    Next item  
End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't assign `html`. It's null now.

Comment: Assign HTML? where do i do that

Comment: You need something like `Set html = ie.document`

Comment: `Set html= ie.Document`

Comment: I did that and now i am ending up with Error 438 Object Does'nt Support this property at pricedata. what should be object data here

Comment: See the answer, it shows you how to get an element by class and get it's inner text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't assign `html` and it's null now.

You should assign it this way:

```
Set html= ie.Document
```

**To get an element by it's class name:**

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As IHTMLDocument
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463544/vba-fetching-data-from-class-name"
While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
While ie.ReadyState < 4
    DoEvents
Wend
Set html = ie.Document
Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink")
If elements.Length > 0 Then
    MsgBox elements(0).innerText
End If
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
```

[image]

Don't forget to add reference to:

- `Microsoft Internet Controls`
- `Microsoft Html Object library`

---

**For that amazon link:**

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate "http://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B00EYCBGNA/ref=dp_olp_new_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=new"
While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
While ie.ReadyState < 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Set html = ie.Document
Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("olpOfferPrice")
For i = 0 To elements.Length - 1
     Sheet1.Range("A" & (i + 1)) = elements(i).innerText
Next i

Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("olpSellerName")
For i = 0 To elements.Length - 1
    Sheet1.Range("B" & (i + 1)) = elements(i).innerText
Next i
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
```

[image]

Comment: It works for stack over flow but when i try for amazon to get the seller names and pricing through this link it shows nothing with the class name http://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B00EYCBGNA/ref=dp_olp_new_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=new

Comment: The post answers your main question but you should use suitable values and logic to be able to extract prices. The answer is really better this way. For example you can extract prices this way:    `Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("olpOfferPrice")` and it returns an array with length of 6.

Comment: I also added your specific case for that amazon link. See edited answer and also pay attention to those 2 `While` commands.

Comment: Also probably you will see price using your currency unit. Here is shows `Rs.`

Comment: Yup got it, Just want to mention that we did not did ie.Quit. The code might not start again once completed